# Updating date with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm currently trying to update automatically the date through JavaScript. The following code is an example where the number increments by 1 each time, but I need to also update the date in the next column by increasing it by a month each time.

```
function repeater_update_order( repeater )
{
    repeater.find('> table > tbody > tr.row').each(function(i){
        $(this).children('td.order').html(i+1);
    });

};
```

I know that you can update a date using the following JavaScript:

```
var x = 1; //or whatever offset
var CurrentDate = new Date();
CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth()+X);
```

How can I use this second code to update the date in a field?

Comment: Depends on how you want to format the date, though there are methods to get a string representation for a Date object. Take a look at the [MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Careful with that month modification. It will roll over from `March 31` to `May 01` instead of `April 30`.

Comment: This works: `var d=new Date(); d = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,1)` http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Vb94B/

Comment: @DCoder thanks for the tip, I realise that but it doesn't matter as all dates will be from the first of the month. Any ideas how I can run it within the function?

Comment: @mplungjan how would I go about using this within the function on the page? Should I put the current date within the cell and then find it with the function that is called?

Comment: Datejs might be helpful: http://www.datejs.com/ (haven't used this yet myself)

Comment: You need to show an example of before and after

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML, the table date values are strings which we interpret as dates. You need to parse that string into a JS Date object, add one month and reconvert to the original string format.

If, as you say, the dates are always on the first of the month then you could short cicuit the process by parsing and converting in one function :

```
  function nextMonth (d) {
    d = d.match (/^(.*)(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(d\d\d\d)(.*)$/
    return d ? d[0] + d[1] + '/' + (d[2] < 11 ? +d[2] + 1 : 1) + '/' + (d[2] >= 11 ? 1 + +d[3] : d[3]) + d[4];
  }
```

This assumes the data is always stored in the string in the format dd/mm/yyyy. If you format differs you will need to adjust accordingly.

If you format is complex or not consistent then you might consider using a date library such as Datejs.